# retrieving data from <li> of a <ul> in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, css, puppeteer

I want to get inner text from HTML ul tag using puppeteer
this is what I used to create the array of inner text but getting error.

```
  const li =  document.querySelector('#year-list-container > div > div.js-profile-timeline-year-list.color-bg-primary.js-sticky > ul').getElementsByTagName('li')
  array = []
  for (let i = 0; i <= li.length - 1; i++) {
    array.push(li[i]);
  }
```

error is this

```
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:15860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15860) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the 
Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

full code, i hvave imported puppeteer so thats not the bug

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  giturl  = ('https://github.com/siddhart1o1');
    await page.goto(giturl , {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})

    let data =  await page.evaluate(()=>{
        let stars  = document.querySelector('#js-pjax-container > div.container-xl.px-3.px-md-4.px-lg-5 > div > div.flex-shrink-0.col-12.col-md-3.mb-4.mb-md-0 > div > div.js-profile-editable-replace > div.d-flex.flex-column > div.js-profile-editable-area.d-flex.flex-column.d-md-block > div.flex-order-1.flex-md-order-none.mt-2.mt-md-0 > div > a:nth-child(3) > span').innerText
        let followers = document.querySelector('#js-pjax-container > div.container-xl.px-3.px-md-4.px-lg-5 > div > div.flex-shrink-0.col-12.col-md-3.mb-4.mb-md-0 > div > div.js-profile-editable-replace > div.d-flex.flex-column > div.js-profile-editable-area.d-flex.flex-column.d-md-block > div.flex-order-1.flex-md-order-none.mt-2.mt-md-0 > div > a:nth-child(1) > span').innerText
        let following = document.querySelector('#js-pjax-container > div.container-xl.px-3.px-md-4.px-lg-5 > div > div.flex-shrink-0.col-12.col-md-3.mb-4.mb-md-0 > div > div.js-profile-editable-replace > div.d-flex.flex-column > div.js-profile-editable-area.d-flex.flex-column.d-md-block > div.flex-order-1.flex-md-order-none.mt-2.mt-md-0 > div > a:nth-child(2) > span').innerText
        let repos = document.querySelector('#js-pjax-container > div.container-xl.px-3.px-md-4.px-lg-5 > div > div.flex-shrink-0.col-12.col-md-9.mb-4.mb-md-0 > div.UnderlineNav.user-profile-nav.d-block.d-md-none.position-sticky.top-0.pl-3.ml-n3.mr-n3.pr-3.color-bg-primary > nav > a:nth-child(2) > span').innerText
        //this code is giving error
        let li = document.querySelector('div.js-profile-timeline-year-list.color-bg-primary.js-sticky > ul').getElementsByTagName('li')
        array = []
        for (let i = 0; i <= li.length - 1; i++) {
          array.push(li[i]);
        }

        return{
            stars,
            followers,
            followinf,
            repos,
            array
        }


    })

    console.log(data)
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Please, add more code. Do you use this fragment in the main Node.js context or in browser context inside page.evaluate()?

Comment: This `i <= li.length` doesn't look right at all

Comment: @vsemozhebuty  yes this is working in browser but not working in page.evaluate()

Comment: @AlonEitan what is wrong in that ?

Comment: [Arrays start at 0](https://i.imgur.com/VRSkSGd.jpg) so `<=` means that you trying to access an undefined offset. It should be `<`

Comment: @AlonEitan i have also used -1

Comment: Oh, I totally missed that sorry. So there's no reason for this not to work, perhaps `document.querySelector('#year-list-container > div > div.js-profile-timeline-year-list.color-bg-primary.js-sticky > ul')` is not returning anything, did you put this code after the HTML?

Comment: @AlonEitan please read my question I am using puppetter and i want to scrap this data from the github page i am sending full code. please have a look at that

Comment: this is actually a github scrapper program

Comment: I think that something is wrong with the selector - `document.querySelector('div.js-profile-timeline-year-list.color-bg-primary.js-sticky > ul').getElementsByTagName('li')` worked for me, but there's no `document.querySelector('#year-list-container')` on the page

Comment: @AlonEitan can you tell me specifically where?

Comment: Try changing `document.querySelector('#year-list-container > div > div.js-profile-timeline-year-list.color-bg-primary.js-sticky > ul').getElementsByTagName('li')` to `document.querySelector('div.js-profile-timeline-year-list.color-bg-primary.js-sticky > ul').getElementsByTagName('li')` - I think that it selects the element's you were trying to select

Comment: @AlonEitan no getting error now also

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas then. Hope someone else will be able to help

Comment: Is there anything else in the error log? You have cited a usual wrapper for errors in promises, but there is no exact error there.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have a typo here:

```js
        return{
            stars,
            followers,
            followinf, // Should be following 
            repos,
            array
        }
```

2. Unfortunately, [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) can only transfer serializable values (roughly, the values JSON can handle). As `getElementsByTagName()` returns a collection of DOM elements that are not serializable (they contain methods and circular references), each element in the collection is replaced with an empty object. You need to return either serializable value (for example, an array of texts or `href` attributes) or use something like [`page.$$(selector)`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) and [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) API. So try this:

```js
  for (let i = 0; i <= li.length - 1; i++) {
    array.push(li[i].innerText);
  }
```